# efficient way to generate non-increasing integer sequence of length n, with each element bounded between j and k

Tags: python, sequence

I need to write a function that generate non-increasing integer sequence of length n, with each element bounded between j and k (inclusive)

i.e. if n = 3, j = 0 and k = 3:

```py
[(3,3,3), (3,3,2), (3,3,1), (3,3,0), (3,2,2), (3,2,1), (3,2,0), (3,1,1), (3,1,0), ... , (1,1,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,0), (0,0,0)]
```

if n is small, I would just use nested for loops, but in case n is very large, I would like to know if there is an efficient method to get such list.

I was thinking of using itertools, but I am not too sure how.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and reverse the elements:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def func(n, j, k):
    for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(j, k+1), n):
        yield c[::-1]

>>> list(func(3, 0, 3))
[(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0), (3, 3, 0), 
 (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (3, 2, 1), (3, 3, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 2), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

As suggested in the comments (thx @CrazyChucky), providing the the iterable in reverse order makes this even more concise and produces the sequences in your suggested order:

```
def func(n, j, k):
    return combinations_with_replacement(range(k, j-1, -1), n)

>>> list(func(3, 0, 3))
[(3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 0), (3, 2, 2), ...
```

And just for the LOLs, here is a recursive hand-written implementation:

```
def func(n, j, k):
    if not n:
        return [[]]
    result = []
    for i in range(k, j-1, -1):
        for comb in func(n-1, j, i):
            result.append([i] + comb)
    return result

>>> func(2, 0, 2)
[[2, 2], [2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: I believe you could supply the `range` in reverse (`range(k, j-1, -1)`), and the combinations would automatically follow suit.

Comment: Good point, amended my answer.

Comment: Just for the record. Length 5, min 0, max 0 took 19.32 seconds with the second approach and 1.36 with the `itertools` one on my machine.